# Oracle Apex get first part of Postcode

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Oracle 11g

APEX 4.2.6.00.03

I have Postcode field in a form. eg. (L10 1TY or WF2 5TG or W7 5RR)

I also have a region look up table from which gives me a region

eg.

- L = Region 1
- WF = Region 2
- W = Region 3

How would I get the first part of the Postcode so I could lookup the value against the region table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to get the first substring that just has characters, something like `regexp_substr(postcode, '^[[:alpha:]]+')`

For example:

```
with t as (
  select 'L10 1TY' as postcode from dual
  union all select 'WF2 5TG' from dual
  union all select 'W7 5RR' from dual
)
select postcode, regexp_substr(postcode, '^[[:alpha:]]+', 1, 1) as region
from t;

POSTCODE REGION 
-------- -------
L10 1TY  L       
WF2 5TG  WF      
W7 5RR   W
```

Read more about [the `regexp_substr()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions150.htm) and [Oracle's support regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_regexp.htm) in the manuals.